# Protocol used by Oracle RMAN to communicate with auxiliary

Tags: oracle, rman

What protocol is used by RMAN to communicate with the server used for backing up/restoring data?

I searched everywhere but couldn't find any docs with this information.

Background: I am developing a proxy that backs up an oracle database to a different store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called the [SBT API](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/websphere/9780071628600/media-management-considerations/ch04lev1sec3). I can't find any free documentation on it, but the process is that a vendor of say a tape library implements the functions of SBT (e.g. `sbtopen()`, `sbtwrite()` and so on), compiles them as a shared library (a `.so` file) and this is placed in the `ORACLE_HOME`. When RMAN starts it looks for a file called `libobk.so` and dynamically links to it. RMAN then calls the functions, and in turn the protocol between the MML (media management layer) and the actual hardware e.g. a tape library, is proprietary.

Comment: [These guys](https://github.com/weisunding/sbt) seem to have figured out the actual C API, which Oracle (foolishly) hides from developers.

Comment: I expect they make available to hardware vendors

Comment: There are lots of creative applications for this API, that could be offered by other developers. For example, how about backing up _directly_ to a cloud? Or integrating with [Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/)? Sigh... Sybase/SQL Server are making the same mistake...

Comment: With Oracle it is all about the $$$

Comment: With _me_ it is all about $$$ too, nothing wrong with that. I call them "fools", because I think, they are not getting as much money as they could be by keeping the source code and even the APIs of non-essential parts closed. Anyway, this is all off-topic... Sorry...

Comment: Sure. But Oracle only want you to back up directly to _their_ cloud. Etc, etc.